# Android Listview SecondLine row

Tags: java, android, xamarin

Im new to android development and trying to learn what i don't 
get is how i can style the XML below.

All tips and help are very welcome.

**I have the following ListView XML**

[image]

**I want to create the following XML**

[image]

**Current XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/LOC_IMAGE"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:width="38dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ondergrondse2" />
    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:width="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/LOC_CODE" />
    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:width="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/LOC_FRACTIE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LOC_NAME"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Niet aanwezig"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="330dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the LOC_NAME TextView under the others ImageVIew And TextView like the picture below

Why downvoting im trying to learn something

Comment: Stefan pleas explain better, trynig to do?, do you want to make that layout reapeat itself within the list?

Comment: I want the LOC_NAME TextView under the other objects

Comment: Create a first linearlayout with vertical orientation which surrounds your horizontal linearlayout and put the textview after the horizontal linearlayout

Comment: Than i got everything below each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nested linearlayouts, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/LOC_IMAGE"
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:width="38dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/ondergrondse2" />
            <TextView
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="60dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/LOC_CODE" />
            <TextView
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="60dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/LOC_FRACTIE" />
                </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/LOC_NAME"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Niet aanwezig"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:width="330dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thnx everyone it works with the example of BUKA thnx

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayouts Order ther ChildViews in a linear way if you want them to be ordererd Verticaly you should change the android:orientation="horizontal"
to android:orientation="vertical", this wil align your views verticaly from top to bottom so to achieve what you want tou shoud do this

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/LOC_IMAGE"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:width="38dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/ondergrondse2" />
        <TextView
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="60dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/LOC_CODE" />
        <TextView
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="60dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/LOC_FRACTIE" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/LOC_NAME"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Niet aanwezig"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="330dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this,just nest the widget

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">``

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/ondergrondse2"
                android:width="38dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="60dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="60dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LOC_NAME"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Niet aanwezig"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="330dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```